# How to define an audio output programmatically on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, audio, text-to-speech, sapi, speech-synthesis

I'm developing a C++ application which implements the Microsoft Speech API (SAPI). I developed numerous functions related to Text-To-Speech. Among them a function which allows the listing of the audio outputs, and a function that allows to define an audio output.

I started developing this program on Windows 7, but now I switched to Windows 10. However, the function that defines the audio output doesn't work anymore. I didn't edited a thing in my code, and on Windows 7 it worked perfectly.

> Here is the code which lists the available audio outputs

```
int getAudioOut( int auOut ) //get audio outputs function
{
    if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
       //Enumerate Audio Outputs
       hr = SpEnumTokens( SPCAT_AUDIOOUT, NULL, NULL, &cpEnum );
       cpEnum->GetCount( &vCount );
       cpEnum->Item( saveAudio, &cpAudioOutToken );
       SpGetDescription( cpAudioOutToken, &dynStr );
       printf( "Defined audio output is: %ls\n\n", dynStr );
       dynStr.Clear();

       //Loop through the audio output list and enumerate them all
       for( audioOut = 0; audioOut <= vCount - 1; audioOut++ )
       {
          cpAudioOutToken.Release();
          cpEnum->Item( audioOut, &cpAudioOutToken );
          SpGetDescription( cpAudioOutToken, &dynStr );
          printf( "Defined Audio Output %i - %ls\n", audioOut, dynStr );
          dynStr.Clear();
       }
       printf( "\n" );
       audioOut = saveAudio;

       cpEnum.Release();
       cpAudioOutToken.Release();
    }
    else
    {
       printf( "Could not enumerate available audio outputs\n" );
    }

    return true;
}
```

> Here is the code which allows the definition of an audio output

```
int setAudioOut( int auOut ) //define audio output function
{
   if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
   {
      hr = SpEnumTokens( SPCAT_AUDIOOUT, NULL, NULL, &cpEnum );
      cpEnum->GetCount( &vCount );
      size_t nOut = auOut;

      if( nOut >= vCount )
      {
         cout << "Not so many audio outputs available! Try again\n" << endl;
      }
      else
      {
         cout << "Success" << endl;
      }

       ULONG audioOut = static_cast<ULONG>( nOut ); //convert nOut to ULONG audioOut

       cpEnum->Item( audioOut, &cpAudioOutToken );
       SpGetDescription( cpAudioOutToken, &dynStr );
       printf( "You chose %ls\n\n", dynStr );
       cpVoice->SetOutput( cpAudioOutToken, TRUE ); //Initialization of the Audio Output
       dynStr.Clear();

       cpEnum.Release();
       cpAudioOutToken.Release();

       saveAudio = audioOut; //define saveAudio to audioOut value
    }
    else
    {
       printf( "Could not set audio output\n" );
    }

    return true;
}
```

When I start my program and call the `getAudioOut` function, I get following listing:

[image: getAudioOut function listing]

The first line shows the default audio output, and the two below are the available outputs. On Windows 7, when I set the second audio output (Lautsprecher / Kopfhörer) as default, then no sound comes out from the first (Digitalaudio), which makes sense. However, on Windows 10 I have reproduced the same procedure but it doesn't work. The audio output is always defined according to the audio menu.

[image: Audio Menu]

My question is, **does anyone have experienced this issue? Is there an alternative to define an audio output programmatically?**

Comment: Sorry, the code you write does not make much sense for me. Like what this line is for `auOut = auOut;`? Running `cpAudioOutToken.Release()` inside and outside the loop is also not a great idea. The do/while loop in the second function is also insane. Maybe you try to cleanup your code first, then the problem will be much more clear. Or it can even disappear eventually.

Comment: I modified the code as you mentioned, but it doesn't change anything :/

Comment: I found out the error ! It came from another function. I post the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the code as @NikolayShmyrev suggested but it didn't change a thing. However, I continued to dig into the problem an found out that the issue came from another function. Indeed, when I switched from Windows 7 to Windows 10, I encountered other problems with the speech synthesis function and the speech to WAV file function. When I started the program and called the `Text-To-Speech` function, everything worked great. When I called the `Speech2Wav` function, it worked too. However, when I recalled the `Text-To-Speech` function, the variable `HRESULT hr = S_OK;` changed its value and no sound was played. The value of `hr` was set to **-2147200968** which corresponds to **Error 0x80045038: SPERR_STREAM_CLOSED** ([source](https://www.hresult.info/FACILITY_ITF/0x80045038)/[list of error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/jj127491(v%3Dmsdn.10)))

To solve this issue I had to define an audio output like this `cpVoice->SetOutput( cpAudioOutToken, TRUE );` in the `Text-To-Speech` function.

This brings us back to the problem I stated above. When I set the audio output in the function `setAudioOut`, I release its value at the end `cpAudioOutToken.Release();`
However, I reuse the same variable in the `Text-To-Speech` function. Its value was set to nothing because I released it when I defined the audio output. This is why the audio output was always set to default. In order to solve the problem, I assigned the value of `cpAudioOutToken` to another variable called `cpSpeechOutToken`.

> Here is the code for the function `setAudioOut`

```
int setAudioOut( int auOut ) //define audio output function
{
   if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
   {
      hr = SpEnumTokens( SPCAT_AUDIOOUT, NULL, NULL, &cpEnum );
      cpEnum->GetCount( &vCount );
      size_t nOut = auOut;

      if( nOut >= vCount )
      {
         cout << "Not so many audio outputs available! Try again\n" << endl;
         return 0;
      }
      else
      {
         cout << "Success" << endl;
      }

      ULONG audioOut = static_cast<ULONG>( nOut ); //convert nOut to ULONG audioOut

      cpEnum->Item( audioOut, &cpAudioOutToken );
      SpGetDescription( cpAudioOutToken, &dynStr );
      printf( "You chose %ls\n\n", dynStr );
      cpVoice->SetOutput( cpAudioOutToken, TRUE ); //Initialization of the Audio Output
      dynStr.Clear();

      cpEnum.Release();
      cpSpeechOutToken = cpAudioOutToken;
      cpAudioOutToken.Release();
      saveAudio = audioOut; //define saveAudio to audioOut value
   }
   else
   {
      printf( "Could not set audio output\n" );
   }
   return true;
}
```

> Here is the code from the `Text-To-Speech` function

```
int ttsSpeak( const char* text ) //Text to Speech speaking function
{
   if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
   {
      string xmlSentence( text );
      hr = SpEnumTokens( SPCAT_VOICES_WIN10, NULL, NULL, &cpEnum );
      //Replace SPCAT_VOICES_WIN10 with SPCAT_VOICES if you want to use it on Windows 7

      cpEnum->Item( saveVoice, &cpVoiceToken ); //get saveVoice token defined at line 175
      cpVoice->SetVoice( cpVoiceToken ); //Initialization of the voice

      //string strText( text );

      int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, xmlSentence.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0 );
      wchar_t* wstr = new wchar_t[ wchars_num ];
      MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, xmlSentence.c_str(), -1, wstr, wchars_num );

      printf( "Text To Speech processing\n" );
      cpVoice->SetOutput( cpSpeechOutToken, TRUE );
      hr = cpVoice->Speak( wstr, SVSFIsXML, NULL );

      saveText = xmlSentence.c_str();

      cpEnum.Release();
      cpVoiceToken.Release();
      delete new wchar_t[ wchars_num ];
  }
  else
  {
     printf( "Could not speak entered text\n" );
  }
  return true;
}
```